# How to get Historical Traffic Data from Here API

Tags: here-api, traffic

Was looking at using the Here API to get some historical traffic data. Their website says they have historical traffic data, but I don't see a way to access it via their API other than getting a time-aware route, which takes historical traffic into account but doesn't give me info about it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several years is not accessible through these APIs. 
Ask to be contacted from contact form on developer.here.com

Answer (score 0):

use  REST API from Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets with layer TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FC1...5

Online documentation is there:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions

look for "Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets"

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate: "Live traffic info recorded from the last days, in 15 munite resolution" -- but would this have historical traffic data, for say, several years ago?

Comment: The Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets are just going back app. a week. This is  used for providing the traffic patterns.